# Getting error code 415 unsupported media type with GetConnect library in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, http, flutter-getx

I am trying to make a GET request with the api key and headers. I keep getting the '415 Unsupported Media Type' error. I have tried including the 'content-type' as 'application/json' in the headers but I still get the same error. There is very little documentation on GetConnect class from the GetX package. I don't understand why the content-type is not being recognised. I apologise if the question is frivolous. I am new to the platform and unaware of the traditions.
Any help is appreicated.

```
    class ApiProvider extends GetConnect {
  Future<Response> getMusicList(String searchQuery) async {
   
    return get('https://shazam.p.rapidapi.com/search?term=' + searchQuery);
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    var headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-rapidapi-key': '[API-KEY]',
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'shazam.p.rapidapi.com'
    };
    httpClient.defaultContentType = "application/json";

    httpClient.addAuthenticator((Request request) async {
      request.headers.clear();    
      request.headers.addAll(headers);
      return request;
    });

    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine in the code. You can try adding `locale: 'en-US'` parameter.

You can always write to the RapidAPI support team at support@rapidapi.com. They are active and would love to help you out.